# What should be ideal data structure for firebase based social networking app

Tags: firebase

I am developing a series of social network app. I am in dilemma what should be good data structure to use for social networking app. I have tried below 2 approaches so far but there are few problems with both approaches so looking for thoughts for the efficient data structure.

**Example1:**

```
{"users":[{"username":"user1","email":"email1@mail.com"}]}

{"posts":[{"title":"title1","postedBy":{"user":{"username":"user1","email":"email1@mail.com"}}}]}
```

In above structure, there is problem if user modify his

> username

then the post has his old username.

**Example 2:**

To Solve above problem we have introduced

> user_id

which will be a reference in user JSON e.g

```
{"users":[{"user_id":"123456","username":"user1","email":"email1@mail.com"}]}
{"posts":[{"title":"title1","postedBy":"123456<user_id>"}]}
```

But in above case query is becoming more complex like in every post we have to do users JSON query to get user data posted by the user.

Comment: 2nd example is the best

Comment: If you are using firebase RTDB, moving to firestore database will be a good option.

Comment: There is no way to answer this question; a 'best' structure is totally dependent on what you want to get out of it and that's not included in the question. Example1 is probably too deep, Example 2 is better but we don't know the function of user_id, username or email - and a /users node will typically have child nodes with the uid as keys. But that's not clear if it does or not. We would really need to understand your use case and some example of what kinds of things you are doing with the data (which may go beyond the scope of SO) unless it's very specific.